# Tkinter change language Dialog Box

Tags: tkinter, localization, dialog

Is there a way to change the language from the dialog boxes with Tkinter, on windows 10 ? I mean, I use in my program the dialog box from colorchooser.askcolor. But the text is written according to the language of my computer, and on my programm I give the possibility to change the language. How to force this dialog box to be in an other language ?

Tank for the help !!!!!